# Finding geolocations within the bounds in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, google-map

I am working with Goole map in a VF page.Consider that Account object has Geolocation field. Based on the user location I have mapped the center point in the map and got the bounds of the map using getBounds() function in javascript.

`GetBounds` returns two Geolocations SouthWest and NorthEast.

How I can query all the accounts within those two geolocations?

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a latitude/longitude pair from those Geolocations on the page, you should be able to find records within a radius of those points via the `DISTANCE` and `GEOLOCATION` functions used in a `WHERE` clause. The specifics of these functions are discussed in the [Geolocation based SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm) documentation.

If the [release notes](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer15/queries) are correct, you can preform queries such as the ones below:

```
Double myLatitude = 10; 
Double myLongitude = 10;
List accountList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude FROM Account WHERE DISTANCE(My_Location_Field__c, GEOLOCATION(:myLatitude, :myLongitude), 'mi') < 10];

Location myLocation = Location.newInstance(10, 10);
Double myDistance = 100;

List accountList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude FROM Account WHERE DISTANCE(My_Location_Field__c, :myLocation, 'mi') < :myDistance];
```

The key of these queries is in the `WHERE` clause. Querying based on the results of a query filtered by a formula to determine the distance between the specified point, provided by the javascript on your page, and the location of each record should provide the behavior you are looking for.

---

Below is an example of a page/controller which would be setup to perform these queries.

## Page Example

```
<apex:actionFunction name="GetRecordsAtLocation" action="{!GetRecordsAtLocation}" rerender="ResultsPanel">
    <apex:param name="Longitude" assignTo="{!Longitude}" value="" />
    <apex:param name="Latitude" assignTo="{!Latitude}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<!-- ... -->

<script>
    var someGeolocation = something.GetBounds(); 

    GetRecordsAtLocation(someGeolocation.Longitude, someGeolocation.Latitude); 
</script>
```

As you can see, you'll need a way to pass the values from your page's javascript, over to the controller. This is where using an `actionFunction` comes in handy.

## Controller Example

```
public List<Account> accountsAtLocation { get; set; }

public Double Longitude { get; set; }
public Double Latitude { get; set; }

public PageReference GetRecordsAtLocation() {

    accountsAtLocation = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude FROM Account WHERE DISTANCE(My_Location_Field__c, GEOLOCATION(:Latitude, :Longitude), 'mi') < 10];

    return null; 
}
```

You'll need a function setup to perform the query based on values set by the `actionFunction`, and then save those records to a variable which you can access on the page.

Comment: Just to add one point here, that to start using geocode you have to Set Up Geocode Clean Rules in the Org. You can get the details here https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/data_dot_com_clean_add_geocode_information_to_all_records.htm

Comment: This code will give you the Geolocations within that distance. My question is to get the geolocation within the Bounds of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Google developer doc helped me. Here is the solution,

```
//Creating the map
var mapOptions = {center: myLatLng ,
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
//Link with page component
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  mapOptions);
//Get the bounds of the map this will return  LatLngBounds
var bounds = map.getBounds();
ver newGeolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(13, 81);
//Bounds will check whether given geolocation exist within the bounds
if(bounds.contains(newGeolocation) {
//Got the location which exist within the current map bounds
}
```

> **google.maps.LatLngBounds** class has the inbuild function
>   **contains(latLng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)** 
>   Return Value:  boolean Returns
>   true if the given lat/lng is in this  bounds.